# Implicit/Explicit Login Filter - Set Data in Filter which can be available to all portlets after login - Webpshere Portal 8

Tags: websphere-portal

I'm unable to do the following:   Any help is appreciated . Thanks .

1) Set some data(Objects) into HttpSession in custom Implicit/Explicit Login Filters and access that data across all the portlets after logging in.

2) Tried this - HttpSession sesson = request.getSession(true) and set an attribute on the session . But unable to access the attribute inside the portlets after logging in .

3)  Last option is Dynacache.  Avoiding this and checking this to see if there is any elegant way doing using Implicit/Explicit login filters.

**Use Case:**  Set some shared data in Implicit / Explicit Login Filters and access it in all portlets after logging in .

References used:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0905_buchwald/0905_buchwald.html

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result with Explicit/Implicit login filter and SessionValidation filter as below:

1. Inside Explicit/Implicit login filter set data as session attribute.
2. Create a SessionValidationFilter  and inside this filter read the attribute from session and set it as request attribute. Now configure this  filter from WAS admin console.
3. Inside the portlet use following code snippet to get the shared data:

   ```
   PortletUtils.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest).getAttribute(attributeName)
   ```

   OR

   ```
   PortletUtils.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest).getAttribute(attributeName)
   ```

Comment: this worked for me. thanks :-). However, can you explain or redirect me to any resource as to why we would need the SessionValidationFilter too.

Comment: If sessionvalidation filter is configured in web sphere portal, then it intercepts all the request(anonymous and authenticated both). So, if you want to perform any check before processing the request, you can do it inside sessionvalidation filter.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to get the HTTPSession from the Portlet API. However most Portal implementations do offer a platform specific way of accessing it.

```
import com.ibm.wps.pb.utils.portlet.PortletUtils;
...
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = PortletUtils.getHttpServletRequest(portletRequest);
HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession();
```

You can use this in your portlet to access the HTTPSession object and then manipulate it as you need.

I don't know how you're trying to pull data from the portlet session but, there is [this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/Joey_Bernal/entry/portlet_session_scope_and_sharing?lang=en) for Portal v5. At quick glance, it seems to imply that you could set something in the HTTP Session and then access it as an application-scoped portlet session attribute. However if this behavior is simply an implementation detail and not part of the official documentation, I wouldn't rely on this to be true in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To share data across portlet once user is logged in is a two step process.

1. Inside Explicit/Implicit login filter set  data as session attribute.
2. Create a ServletFilter and inside this filter read the attribute from session and set it as  request attribute. Now configure  this servlet filter with wps.ear as follows:

   a. Export the servlet filter as JAR and place this JAR at

   `C:\IBM\WebSphere\PortalServer\shared\app\`

   Note: I assume that WebSphere portal server is installed at C:\IBM

   b. Add filter mapping for your custom filter in web.xml and web_merged.xml present at

   `C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\config\cells\10Cell\applications\wps.ear\deployments\wps\wps.war\WEB-INF\`
3. Inside the portlet use following code snippet to get the shared data:
   `PortletUtils.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest).getAttribute(attributeName)`

   or

   `PortletUtils.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest).getAttribute(attributeName)`
4. Restart the portal server.